# "Fetch as Google" only puts my page in the seach index for 30 minutes

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, fetch-as-google

Fetch as Google only works for 30 minutes.  After that, the page is not shown in the Google index.

Here this is my robots.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Fetch as Google is not immediate. The regular googlebot will come by 1-2 days later to properly fetch the page and index it officially.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't have anything to do with your robots.txt file.

Comment: @closetnoc why can he find the page for 30 minutes if it isn't immediate?    I've never encountered this behavior of Google before.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Google was getting a lot of manipulation with the Fetch and Render and Submit to Index and changed how this feature works. It does fetch the page and changes the SERPs, however, it is not a permanent change until the regular googlebot comes by in 1-2 days. Specifically how this woks is a complete mystery to me. However, Google did mention somewhere in it's vast communications a few years back that it is now a temporary change until the regular googlebot indexes the page. I only mention it because I have seen changes revert back before or not taken at all. Cheers!!

Comment: How are you confirming whether the page is in Google's index?

Comment: If the page was blocked by `robots.txt` then you wouldn't even get your 30 minutes. You'd get an immediate warning ("Blocked") that the page was blocked by `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

> Fetch as Google only works for 30 minutes. After that, the page is not shown in the Google index..... What did I do wrong here?

Robots.txt has nothing to do with it.

You need to look at the pages that you're trying to make google index using the "fetch as google" feature and see that they follow the Google Webmaster Guidelines completely. This means don't post extreme adult content and/or hate speeches that would hurt the community, etc. Instead, it means make quality content that is valuable to your guests.

It would also help to make sure that the sitemaps you have submitted to Google's search console (which I hope you did at least one) lists every publicly accessible URL on your site so that Google can quickly index your site.

The "fetch as google" tool is there to help you troubleshoot your site so that you can get an idea as to if a hacker got into it (and made google see something different). It's also a good idea to use fetching tools on other webmaster consoles such as Bing webmaster tools and Yandex.

Comment: Plus 1 for trouble shooting versus Google hurry the hell up! BTW- Hey Mike!

Comment: thanks for your answer but my site has more than 10,000 links i added to google sitemap is it possible to check samaretan.com ? when i search some words i posted in my site in google its not appears in search results

Comment: I can see why google won't index the home page. There's no content (text). I understand you like using javascript code, but requiring javascript for any kind of content to be displayed to the user is the first sign of madness.